# Replacing text with mixed special characters in a file

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed

I'm trying to replace a string **VCC_TGL** to **$G_CORNER_SQL_DETAILS($corner+vcc_tgl)**
I have tried using the perl one liner, but it is missing the **$** character.

```
my $i="VCC_TGL";
my $test="\$G_CORNER_SQL_DETAILS(\$corner+vcc_tgl)";
print "replace $i with $test\n";
`perl -pi.back -e 's/$i/$test/' configure.tcl`;
```

The output im getting on executing the above perl script is ,

```
set vccio G_CORNER_SQL_DETAILS(corner+vcc_tgl)
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string containing special shell characters, e.g. `$`, through shell parsing, i.e. they are processed by the shell and therefore get lost:

```
$ perl -e '$test="XXX\$YYY"; qx/set -x; echo $test/' 
+ echo XXX
```

Back-ticks, `qx//` and `system("...")` are prone to such problems and are unsafe in general.

You should instead use the safe array version of `system()`, i.e. bypass the shell completely so that parameters are passed into the called command as-is:

```
 $ perl -e '$i="AAA"; $test="XXX\$YYY"; system(qw(echo perl -pi.back -e), "s/$i/$test/", qw(configure.tcl));'
 perl -pi.back -e s/AAA/XXX$YYY/ configure.tcl
```